# Convert all strings with numbers to integers in DataFrames

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I am using pandas with `openpyxl` to process multiple Excel files into a single Excel file as output. In this output file, cells can contain a combination of numbers and other characters or exclusively numbers, and all cells are stored as text.

I want all cells that only contain numbers in the output file to be stored as numbers. As the columns with numbers are known (5 to 8), I used the following code to transform the text to floats:

```
for dictionary in list_of_Excelfiles
    dictionary[DataFrame][5:8].astype(float)
```

However, this manual procedure is not scalable and might be prone to errors when other characters than numbers are present in the column. As such, I want to create a statement that transforms any cell with only numbers to an integer.

What condition can filter for cells with only numbers and transform these to integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use try and except and apply map, here is a full example:

create some random data for example:

```
def s():
    return [''.join(random.choices([x for x in string.ascii_letters[:6]+string.digits], k=random.randint(1, 5))) for x in range(5)]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for c in range(4):
    df[c] = s()
```

define a try and except func:

```
def try_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

apply on each cell:

```
df2 = df.applymap(try_int)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Ezer! I think this will be the solution that I look for, but I am a bit confused. The try_int function requires as input variable a DataFrame right? Then how can this be applied on cell level?

Comment: Hi Ezer, I think I almost got it to work, but I'll need a little extra help. I have written loops such that each cell can be read as a string by the Try&Except function. However, I am having difficulty with adopting the function to my code. Could you please take a look at the edited question above?

Comment: sorry, don't fully understand the situation, applymap is a dataframe method applying a given func on each cell separately

Comment: I think that should work as the loops help apply the fucntion on cell level.  However, the problem is that there is a discrepancy between our try_int functions. You use no input argument while I am using try_int(cell_numeric). Should I implement the function differently? Should the cell_numeric be altered? Or do you see another problem that I am missing in the implementation of the try_int function?

Comment: both ways seem legit, can't solve your error without seeing the data (this is not to imply I will be able once I see it), try following the random data example

Comment: In the dataframes, there are floats for nan values and the others are strings. Do these floats hindering the use of try_int? I try: for dataframe in d_sheets.keys():
    dictionary[dataframe].applymap(try_int), but this does not transform the numbers to integers. When I run your solution, it works perfectly, but not on my dataframes yet....

Comment: Hi Ezer, the solution works! Instead of dictionary[dataframe].applymap(try_int), I needed to use dictionary[dataframe] = ]dictionary[dataframe].applymap(try_int)